# d3.js, is it possible to append hyperlinks to GeoJSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have started to play with d3.js and json recently and after not finding answer in other threads I state my question directly here.
I wonder if its possible to accomplish following task with d3 library:

I have working example of loaded and projected geojson file made according to Scott Murray's book - Interactive Data Visualization (https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book)

Here is my code (from book):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Zoom/pan map example</title>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>

</html>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 500;
            var h = 300;

            //Define map projection
            var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                                   .translate([w/2, h/2])
                                   .scale([500]);

            //Define path generator
            var path = d3.geo.path()
                             .projection(projection);

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            //Load in GeoJSON data
            d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {

                //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
                svg.selectAll("path")
                   .data(json.features)
                   .enter()
                   .append("path")
                   .attr("d", path)
                   .style("fill", "steelblue");

            });

        </script>

<body>
</html>
```

- json file from chapter 12 - https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/tree/master/chapter_12

Now,
I want  -  let's say -  polygon representing state Washington (top left corner) to be clickable, "holding" hyperlink. In other words - is it possible to append hyperlink to that polygon ? 
Second thing - is it possible to insert text (state numbers) into polygons so that text will remain inside polygons and not crossing its borders ?

I hope its clear and I would be thankful if someone skilled enough could provide solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Svg has a `<a>` tag you can insert dinamically:
http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_text.asp.

This is probably the way to go

Comment: Thanks for hint, I'll look for further ifno a and give it a try,
menwhile any idea how to embed link directly into JSON file ?